# How do I delete a file that was opened by xmlreader in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xmlreader

I've researched several questions but none of the answers I found has helped.  The goal of this function is to modify an xml file.  I read the original file and write the old stuff and the new stuff to the new file.  All of this works perfectly.  The problem arises when I'm done and need to delete the old file and move the new one.

The error being received is that the jnv_config.xml is in use by another process (the reader file.)

Removing the Close and/or Dispose does not solve the problem.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("jnv_config.xml"))
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("jnv_temp.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      // Read the file, write to the other file - this part works perfectly.
      // No filestreams nor anything else is created in here.
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    reader.Close();
    writer.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
    writer.Dispose();
}
// Delete the old file and copy the new one
File.Delete("jnv_config.xml");
//File.Move("jnv_temp.xml", "jnv_config.xml");
```

I'm using VS2012 (NET 4.5), C#, Standard Windows Forms project.

Comment: Since you have the `using` keyword, you don't have to call `reader.Dispose()` or `writer.Dispose()`.  They will be sent to `Garbage Collection` once they fall out-of-scope (outside the `using`).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you copying the XML from one file to the another, then deleting the original file and renaming the new one to the original? Isn't this a no-op?

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy I assume that CramerTV's actual code does change the XML, but this is a simplified version that just demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy, if the user changes something in the application's configuration I change the configuration file to reflect those changes.  The point of my comment was to ensure folks understood I wasn't creating any new objects that could be holding the file descriptor open.

Comment: Yeah, thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that it's this `XmlReader` that still has the file open?  Have you tried using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to confirm that there are no open file handles for the config file before this code executes?

Comment: You are correct sir.  I had opened the file in another function without using the 'using' construct.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that many NTFS file-handling functions (especially DELETEs) are slightly asynchronous.  Trying adding a Sleep or Wait for at least 0.2 sec before the RENAME.

---

As that did not work, I would instead suggest putting the Sleep/Wait *before* and then slowly increasing it until it works.  If you get to some unreasonably large time span (like say 10 seconds) and it still does not work, then I think that you can fairly conclude that the problem is that you `XmlReader` is not being released as long as you stay in this code.

In which case you may need to do something to insure that it is getting Disposed completely, like forcing GC to run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It's actually throwing the exception on the delete call itself.  I did try putting in a delay before and after the delete but no joy.

Comment: why don't you wrap your code around a try catch and properly trap the exception..? also how does it know where the location of that file is if you are not passing the file Path..? can't you capture that from where you load the .XML file..? also do you need to Flush() the file before closing and or Disposing..?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is ready before you delete it. If your working with large files perhaps call code via a loop for a couple of seconds.

```
private void IsFileOpen(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {

        if (ex is IOException && IsFileLocked(ex)) {
            // do something here, either close the file if you have a handle or as a last resort terminate the process - which could cause corruption and lose data
        }
    }
}

private static bool IsFileLocked(Exception exception)
{
    int errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(exception) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
    return errorCode == 32 || errorCode == 33;
}
```